# Receiving data at regular intervals (MODBUS TCP JAVA)

Tags: java, tcp, modbus

I'm currently working on a Modbus TCP JAVA project using the jamod library. So far, I'm able to read & write to the Modbus network (gateway & some sensors from 4-noks) without any issues. My next step is to receive the data of the sensors automatically.

The devices I'm using are sending their registers to the Modbus-Gateway at regular intervals (about 20-60seconds). Unfortunately, I'm having some problems in receiving these data.

The Gateway has a register in which it's counting the received messages and it does receive data of the sensors, but how can I display these data onto my PC using java (jamod, or maybe another library)?

I have been searching and trying for the last week and I'm out of ideas. Would be very nice to get some information on how this goal can be achieved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you want to display the data and what your intentions are.

On the full-solution end of the spectrum this is what an HMI/SCADA system does for you ([www.inductiveautomation.com](http://www.inductiveautomation.com), for example).

On the roll-it-yourself end of the spectrum it sounds like you just need to continually poll the gateway for the registers you're interested in and maybe display it on a webpage.

Where do you land on this spectrum?

Comment: The "roll-it-yourself" spectrum is the one I'm looking for (in some way), but I don't want to continually poll the gateway for the registers, because each time I pull the gateway the registers of the sensors are checked (Am I correct with this?) The solution I'm looking for is some kind of listening to the gateway, so that it keeps pushing the automatically received messages/values (from the sensors) to my pc/javaprogramm. Is this even possible? If not what is the automatic transmission of the sensor used for then?

Comment: The fact that the sensors are sending their data to the Modbus gateway is a detail of their implementation. If the gateway is purpose built for these sensors they may or may not even be using Modbus to send the values to the gateway. Whether or not you'll be able to listen to the gateway is again going to be an implementation detail - there's no subscription mechanism in Modbus.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I figured it out: the explanation seems to be wrong (or I misinterpreted it). There is no automatic transmission - I was confused about the register "Transmission Time" of the sensors, which is used for setting the measuring period. Example: Transmission Time set on to 60s - client is able to read a new value every 60s (or a new value is written into the register).